# Access the button in parent view from a switch android

Tags: android

I have an issue accessing the view from the parent of a compoundbutton.

```
((Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.push_switch)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        if (rowItem.getPush().equals("N")) {
            rowItem.setFollow(true);
            rowItem.setPush("Y");
            setFollowTickGreen(rowItem, convertView);
        }
        else if (rowItem.getPush().equals("Y")) {
            rowItem.setPush("N");
        }

    }
});
```

This code shows my switch button but I need to get access to `convertView` to change something else when this button is pressed.

This is being done inside an adapter, so the switch code is in the `getView` function but the `setFollowTickGreen` is outside of that function.

I can't set `convertView` as final as it changes throughout the `getView` function.
I understand that the compoundButton is the switch but the switch is at the same level that I want to access a `Button`.

Is there a general way of doing this? 
This would be similar for other situations, as well as compoundbuttons I assume.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help..

```
final View tmpConvertView=convertView;
((Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.push_switch)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        if (rowItem.getPush().equals("N")) {
            rowItem.setFollow(true);
            rowItem.setPush("Y");
            setFollowTickGreen(rowItem, tmpConvertView);
        }
        else if (rowItem.getPush().equals("Y")) {
            rowItem.setPush("N");
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Using this, could you then make a change to something within tmpConvertView?

Comment: Ofcourse you can, **final** in reference variables (tmpConvertView for eg.) merely implies the reference value that the variable holds cannot be changed However You could add a view remove children and do whatever you wish with the object the reference value points to :)

Comment: Yeah I'm with you, makes perfect sense. It's just saying you can't change the reference that tmpConvertView is pointing to. Not what is within that. Cheers, I'll try it!

Comment: Cool.Seems sheepish of me but do mark it as an answer:)

Comment: Yeah of course, I've got an error on the switch at the moment so I can't test it. The switches are changing as I'm scrolling up and down the list view. Bizarre!